# Subversion command line - Killed 9 error message

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon, subversion

I installed subversion via Homebrew on my M1 Mac running macOS 11.4, and every time I run the `svn` command I get an error `Killed: 9` with no other log messages. The version installed is the latest arm build (subversion--1.14.1_2.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz).

Has anyone run into this issue? I assume it is some system process killing the app?

Update... looking in the crash reports under console this looks to be related to code signing...

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000032, 0x00000001045c0000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x2
```

Comment: Hi @Michael - not sure if this is the issue, but have you given terminal permission to do things with the part of the filesystem where the svn is trying to be done?

Comment: @MrR Yeah, I've given terminal permissions, it looks like it is failing because of a code signing issue. I installed another package and see the same behavior.

Comment: There's a chance it's not code signed (or not properly) and with new requirements on M1 it's being killed. The linked Q&A should answer how to apply a signature yourself. If that doesn't work, [edit]ing will reopen.

Comment: @grg So... in my case I found searching through github issues that some people had success reinstalling subversion and all of its dependencies like:

`brew reinstall subversion $(brew deps subversion)`

This actually resolved the issue for me, and fixed the same issue I saw with another homebrew package (which must have had a common dependency).

No clue why a re-install fixed things... but the code signing article you linked is definitely interesting for future reference.

Comment: @Michael Nice! Please post an answer with your findings, I'm sure that will help others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found searching through GitHub issues that some people had success reinstalling subversion and all of its dependencies like:

```
brew reinstall subversion $(brew deps subversion)
```

This actually resolved the issue for me, and fixed the same issue I saw with another homebrew package (which must have had a common dependency).

I didn't find an explanation as to why this resolves the issue. Either the signatures can become corrupt, or a newer version of homebrew makes a change to fix the problem. If you aren't running the latest homebrew it is probably a good idea to update first then reinstall.